# Why is $\big\{X:X\subseteq\{3,2,a\}\text{ and }|X|=4\big\}$ empty?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Write out the following set by listing its elements between braces:

$$\big\{X:X\subseteq\{3,2,a\}\text{ and }|X|=4\big\}=\emptyset$$

The above answer is correct, however can someone explain why this is so? If the size of $X$ must be $4$, why can the only element be none?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hint: $X$ must be a subset of the given set. How many elements are in that given set?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try creating a list of every subset of $\{3,2,a\}$. You get the following:

$$\newcommand{\set}[1]{\left\{ #1 \right\}}\begin{align*}
&\varnothing \\
&\set{3} \\
&\set{2} \\
&\set{3, 2} \\
&\set{a} \\
&\set{3, a} \\
&\set{2, a} \\
&\set{3, 2, a}
\end{align*}$$

Remember that, for finite sets, $|X|$ gives you the number of elements in $X$.

Do any of the above sets $X$ have $|X|=4$? Clearly, not.

Hence, the collection of subsets of $\set{3,2,a}$ with precisely $4$ elements -- that is, the set

$$\set{X \mid X \subseteq \set{3,2,a} \text{ and } |X| = 4}$$

must be empty: no set satisfies those conditions.

---

Remember, you are being asked to give a list of the sets $X$ which meet the conditions

- $X \subseteq \set{3,2,a}$
- $|X|=4$

a "set of sets," if you will. You are not being asked to list the members of such a set, but the sets that meet the conditions.

Comment: Thank you so much! This breaks it down! So I can think of the empty set answer in this context as a "No solutions"?

Comment: Essentially, yeah.

Answer (score 4):

On the left we have a set of all sets $X$, that are subsets of set $\{3,2,a\}$ and have $4$ elements. But the subset of set with $3$ elements can have at most $3$ elements, so there aren't any such sets $X$. That's why on the right side we have an empty set.

Comment: Thank you so much this breaks it down! So I can think of the empty set answer as a "No solutions?"